# Is there any difference between spatial correlation and spatial autocorrelation?

Tags: spatial

What is spatial correlation? Is it the same with spatial auto-correlation or it is different?

Comment: Can you provide the context in which you saw these? I am familiar with spatial auto-correlation, but I think spatial correlation may be non-standard. It would help to interpret the use of the term if the context in which it was used were given.

Comment: i just found about spatial autocorrelation in this article http://booksite.elsevier.com/brochures/hugy/SampleContent/Spatial-Autocorrelation.pdf

Comment: but i couldn't find any explanation about spatial correlation

Comment: I believe close votes are motivated by the lack of context. Could you perhaps provide more details about the application you are interested in, and what is your current understanding of simple correlation as opposed to spatial correlation?

Comment: actually i'm doing a research in survival analysis. i was reading about the SMR method to discover the relative risk for disease. so there are some drawbacks from this SMR method.One of the disadvantages is it cannot cover for a small region or area. so Poisson-gamma model had been introduced to overcome this drawbacks. but there also disadvantage in using Poisson-gamma model as it inability to cope with spatial correlation. so, what is the meaning of spatial correlation here?